# Block posts that contain the string "drozforskolin.org"

Tags: feature-request, spam

Most spam posts that advertise wellness products seem to involve a website called `drozforskolin.org`.

[Exhibit A](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/36697)
[Exhibit B](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/36358)
[Exhibit C](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/36443)
[Exhibit D](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/36082)
[Exhibit E](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/36029)

I therefore propose this: **By blocking any post that contains the string `drozforskolin.org`<sup>1</sup>, we can stop a considerable amount of spam at its source.**

<sup>1 - Only testing if a post contains this string is prone to false positives. One can use this regex to check if a post actually involves drozforskolin.org: `http://(www\.)?drozforskolin\.org[/\\].+[/\\]`</sup>

Comment: This seems like a temporary measure. I mean there are tons and tons of such sites. We would need to block all of them. If you see such site, just report it as spam and I'm sure someone will clean it up :)

Comment: Is it normal for a feature request to receive no votes (neither up nor down) for one full hour?

Comment: @dorukayhan no, but that doesn't make it improbable. Depends on the feature request and how easy it is to agree/disagree with it.

Comment: Well, take a look at [all the other things we should block](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/blob/6fdeadd2f4a11df767fc19e594f0704cb74af4f7/findspam.py#L204).

Answer (score 4):

Generally, URLs are only added to blacklists if they are persistent problems over a long time. Altering the blacklist on Stack Overflow can only be done by an employee, not a moderator, so it's reserved for the most irritating cases.

These folks would have been on the edge of being eligible for a blacklist, spamming that link irregularly for 110 posts since 2014, but it looks like cases like this aren't being added to the blacklist anymore.

It appears that blacklisting of specific URLs got removed in favor of more general categories of blocked sites. That makes sense, given how effective the newer anti-spam measures have been in detecting and blocking new posts from spammers. Few spammers stick with the same URL for long.

The spam that made it through from this group was caught quickly by the community and destroyed in each case. Each destroyed spam post fed into the anti-spam system and made it harder for them to post this. This isn't the only such URL being spammed for health products, so the best solution may just be to rely on community identification and more intelligent blocking by the system based on past spam removal.

Comment: `Few spammers stick with the same URL for long` Then it makes sense to not bother blocking specific URLs from appearing in posts...